# Handle null values in the map callback

Tags: javascript

Here is the input dataset:

```js
const data = {
  TripResults: {
    Depth: [ 577, 694, 810 ],
    Speed: [ 150, 150, 150 ],
    Frequency: [ 3, 3, 3 ]
  },
  SurveyResults: null
}
```

The following approach does not take of care null object (`"SurveyResults": null`), it throws an error. I wonder how I should handle this situation?

```
Object.entries(data).map(([name, properties]) => { /* do something */ })
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I do not want `SurveyResults` which is null to be taken care in the `map` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a filtering and check the value.

```
result = Object
    .entries(data)
    .filter(([_, v]) => v !== null)  // add a filtering
    .map(([name, properties]) => ({
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just

```js
const data = {"TripResults": {"Depth": [577,694,810],"Speed": [150,150,150],"Frequency": [3,3,3]},"SurveyResults": null}

Object.entries(data).map(([name, properties]) => {
 if (properties) { // properties are not null
    console.log(properties)
 }
});
```